# How to insert PHP array into SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-server

I'm trying to insert php array into sql database like this:

```
$i=1    
$sql="INSERT INTO table(itemname) VALUES ('$_SESSION[someVariable][$i]')";
```

however, the name in the database is always `Array[1]`. it is not the value contained in `$_SESSION[someVariable][$i]`

I wonder if there is anyway to declare this? I know I'm messing up with the quotes

Comment: What do you mean with *i1*? That is invalid syntax. You mean *'i1'* or *$i1* or something else?

Comment: @trincot **i1** is a valid array key

Comment: Not unless it is defined as a constant.

Comment: `$array['i1']='fish';echo $array['i1'];` =fish

Comment: Yes, but you put quotes. I don't see those in the question. That is why I asked. OK, I get it, it is the syntax where the quotes are around the whole expression. My bad.

Comment: you may get a notice, but its still valid

Comment: I changed i1 to someVariable it's passed by $_session from last page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you embed array items in a string, make sure to embrace them in curly braces:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table(itemname) VALUES ('{$_SESSION[$somevariable][$i]}')";
```

Alternatively, use string concatenation:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table(itemname) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION[$somevariable][$i] . "')";
```

or a temporary variable:

```
$itemname = $_SESSION[$somevariable][$i];
$sql="INSERT INTO table(itemname) VALUES ('$itemname')";
```

PS, I've replaced `i1` with `$somevariable`. You've changed it to `somevariable` after the discussion in comments, but being a variable, it needs a `$`, of course.

Comment: Thank you! The curly braces are what I'm missing!

Answer (score 3):

You need curly brackets to use an array in a string:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table(itemname) VALUES ('{$_SESSION[i1][$i]}')";
```

The reason you were getting `Array[1]` is because the array was being converted to a string `Array` and `$i` was 1.